# d3 mouse event, add circles on click

Tags: html, reactjs, d3.js, canvas

I need to add in my code that when I click it, more circles and of different radius are added, I have been stuck up to this point

```js
function dragstarted(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().attr("stroke", "black");
}

function dragged(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = event.x).attr("cy", d.y = event.y);
}

function dragended(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("stroke", null);
}

const drag = d3.drag()
  .on("start", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("end", dragended);

const height = 300,
  width = 700
radius = 20

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
  .attr("stroke-width", 2);

const circles = d3.range(10).map(i => ({
  x: Math.random() * (width - radius * 1) + radius,
  y: Math.random() * (height - radius * 1) + radius,
}));

svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(circles)
  .join("circle")
  .attr("cx", d => d.x)
  .attr("cy", d => d.y)
  .attr("r", radius)
  .attr("fill", (d, i) => d3.schemePastel1[i % 100])
  .call(drag);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

I need to create something like that, that can move the circles and add more circles by clicking

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

- Move the drawing to a callable function
- On click, push a new circle to the array of circles, using the `clientX` and `clientY` of the event and redraw.

```js
function dragstarted(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).raise().attr("stroke", "black");
}

function dragged(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("cx", d.x = event.x).attr("cy", d.y = event.y);
}

function dragended(event, d) {
  d3.select(this).attr("stroke", null);
}

const drag = d3.drag()
  .on("start", dragstarted)
  .on("drag", dragged)
  .on("end", dragended);

const height = 300,
  width = 700,
  maxRadius = 20;

const circles = d3.range(10).map(i => ({
  x: Math.random() * (width - maxRadius * 2) + maxRadius,
  y: Math.random() * (height - maxRadius * 2) + maxRadius,
  radius: Math.random() * (maxRadius - 2) + 2,
}));

const svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
  .attr("stroke-width", 2)
  .on("click", (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    circles.push({
      x: event.clientX,
      y: event.clientY,
      radius: Math.random() * (maxRadius - 2) + 2,
    });
    drawCircles();
  })

function drawCircles() {
  svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(circles)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("cx", d => d.x)
    .attr("cy", d => d.y)
    .attr("r", d => d.radius)
    .attr("fill", (d, i) => d3.schemePastel1[i % 9])
    .call(drag);
}

drawCircles();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```